# Expression for when something "hits you", but in a positive way?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I'm trying to express being shocked in a good way, but all I can find are negative phrases such as:

- "It hit me like a ton of bricks."
- "It hit me like a bucket of ice cold water."

I would like to know if there are some ways to say it in a positive way, as in being shocked in a good way. Thank you so much!

**Edit:** Pardon me, I should've added context before! I'm translating a sentence in Spanish, in which someone is saying they were shocked (they describe it as being hit suddenly) and very touched (therefore, it's in a positive light).

The answers supplied by Dan and J O S H are exactly what I needed, both *"It took my breath away"* and *"It blew me away"* work perfectly.

I'd still like to thank you kindly, all of you! I appreciate your help immensely, having found this forum feels like a blessing. However, I'm not certain as to how to proceed now, do I delete the question? Once more, thank you for all your help!

Comment: enlightened maybe? or realize?

Comment: are you looking for *become aware of*? perhaps look into *epiphany* or *revelation* on [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com)

Comment: Thanks for adding some additional context; it's also great to know that you've found your answer! Please don't delete the question now. Part of the idea of this site is to serve as a resource, so that if other people Google the same question in the future, they will be able to find this post and benefit from the answers. You've done the right thing by accepting the answer that helped you the most; this is the best way to express your thanks on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It blew me away***, perhaps.

*Blow away* - To astonish, delight, or thrill; to impress extremely, to overwhelm. (OED)

1974   J. M. Young et al. We are being played or blown Away (Library of Congress MS sheet music) (Eu 478437)   ***Blown, blown, blown away*** By my soft, tequila-fingered lady.

1975   Washington Post 24 May e32/4 (cartoon caption)    *Days like this just **blow me away**—seems like all the world's at peace with itself.*

1995   Q June 102/3   *You Really Got Me by The Kinks. I heard it when I was at school and **it really blew me away**.*

Answer (score 4):

**Dawned on me**.

It has a positive connotation, insinuating one possesses a level of intelligence in order to think critically about the phenomenon. It is much less aggressive than the other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

***And then it hit me***, there's even a single word for this: ***eureka***.

---

*it hit me*

> it occurred to me, I suddenly thought of it –[reverso.net](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/Then%20it%20hit%20me)

---

eu·re·ka  (yo͝o-rē′kə) interj.

> Used to express triumph upon finding or discovering something. –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Eureka)

See also, [eureka effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect) : "known as the **aha! moment** or **eureka moment**" –Wiki

Answer (score 2):

epiphany: a moment when you suddenly feel that you understand, or suddenly become conscious of (Cambridge English Dictionary)

Example:  I had an epiphany; love at first sight really happens.

Answer (score 1):

Something like " and that is when realisation struck" "everything fell into place" "crystal clear". Please provide the sentence you are using it in, context helps us help you

Answer (score -1):

A *pleasant surprise* is an expression of two words with contradictory meaning used together that conveys the meaning you want